# Using a saved model to test data through Java code (Weka)

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, machine-learning-model

I'm completely new to Machine Learning, so my understanding might be wrong in some cases. I'm trying to test data via loading a saved model through Java Code using weka.

```
    Instances testingData = readArffFile(testFile);
            try
            {
                LibSVM cls = (LibSVM) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(model);

                Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(testingData);
                eval.crossValidateModel(cls, testingData, 10, new Random(1));
              //eval.evaluateModel(cls, testingData);
}
```

When I saved the model, I had used cross validation.
Now I'm a bit confused, whether to use `eval.crossValidateModel()` or `eval.evaluateModel()`.

If I use `evaluateModel()`, it gives me wrong accuracy (much higher than it should be). I think this is because the line `<Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(testingData);>` trains it on the same data and then later on test on the same data. This is not what I want. I want to test data on the model without training (I think a model is saved after training)

If I use `eval.crossValidateModel()`, I think it is still training the model again, because as far as I know crossvalidation splits the dataset into k-folds and then performs training on k-1, then tests on the remaining fold.

So is there a way to only perform testing using this loaded model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `eval` on train data.
`Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);`

If you don't have the train data then use:

`Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(test);
eval.useNoPriors();`

After creating `eval` use `eval.evaluateModel(classifier, test);` to classify test data.